# Working with ProgressBar and ComboBox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, combobox, backgroundworker

I'm in trouble with a `Marquee` `ProgressBar`. I need to execute a method (`refreshList()`) to get a `List<string>`. Then I assign this `List` to a `ComboBox`, so `ComboBox` refreshes with the new `Items`. As `refreshList()` take 3 or 4 sec, I wanted to run a `Marquee` `ProgressBar`. But I couldn't. `ProgressBar` is ok, but `ComboBox` doesn't load new `Items`.

My `refreshList()` method:

```
private void refreshList(List<string> list)
{
    albumList.DataSource = null;
    albumList.DataSource = list;
}
```

I have the following code, it works fine:

```
private void changeDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fbd.RootFolder     = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    folderPath = "";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        folderPath     =  fbd.SelectedPath;
        refreshList(N.getList(folderPath));

    }
}
```

But I added a `ProgressBar` and wrote this code:

```
private void changeDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fbd.RootFolder     = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    folderPath = "";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        folderPath     =  fbd.SelectedPath;
        bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
}
```

And I placed `refreshList()` in `doWork()` method:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    refreshList(N.getList(folderPath));
}
```

But unfortunately this isn't working. Can anybody help me solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I summarize a TL;DR version of your question? Setting a data source `albumList.DataSource = list;` takes 3-4 seconds, how to show a marquee progress bar while it's assigning? Is it correct?

Comment: Are you sure the BackgroundWorker class is wired up to the DoWork event (i.e. do you have `bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;` in your code?). I also can't see where you are stopping and starting the `ProgressBar`

Comment: It seems to me this code can't be compiled?What is `folderPath` in `bgWorker_DoWork`.

Comment: @  Neolisk - Not exactly, partially. `N.getList(folderPath)` takes 3-4 secs. Then how to show a marquee progress bar while this method is running.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - folderPath is probably a field in the class. I don't think all the code is here...

Comment: @ dash - I'm running `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` and think this is starting the progressbar. I may be wrong. A not stopping the progressbar anywhere.

Comment: @CoolBrain - you have to tell bgWorker what method to call when you call `RunWorkerAsync()` - you do this by wiring up the DoWork event, which is what is fired when you call RunWorkerAsync. Did you use the Visual Studio Designer to do all of this?

Comment: Look at this topic on MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @  Hamlet Hakobyan - `folderPath =  fbd.SelectedPath;` `fbd` is `FolderBrowsingDialog`. `folderPath` is a global string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MarqueeAnimationSpeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed.aspx) and [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value.aspx) properties of the ProgressBar control to stop and start the Marquee. There's no need to use [WorkerReportsProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx)* as you aren't incrementing a normal progress bar - you just want to "spin" the Marquee.

You can do something like the following:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Stop the progress bar to begin with
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;             
        //If you wire up the event handler in the Designer, then you don't need 
        //the following line of code (the designer adds it to InitializeComponent)
        //backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void changeDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        folderPath = "";
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            folderPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
            //This line effectively starts the progress bar
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 10;                 
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); //Calls the DoWork event

        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = N.getList(folderPath); //Technically this is the only work you need to do in the background
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //these two lines effectively stop the progress bar
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        //Now update the list with the result from the work done on the background thread 
        RefreshList(e.Result as List<String>);
    }


    private void RefreshList(List<String> results)
    {
        albumList.DataSource = null; //You don't need this line but there is no real harm.
        albumList.DataSource = list;
    }
```

Remember to wire up the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted via the Properties bar, Events section in the designer.

To begin with, we start the ProgressBar's animation by setting the MarqueeAnimationSpeed property to a non-zero positive number as part of your successful folder selection.

Then, after calling RunWorkerAsync, the code builds your list in the DoWork method, then assigns the result to the DoWorkEventArgs, which get passed to the RunWorkerCompleted event (which fires when DoWork is finished).

In the `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` method, we stop the progress bar (and set it's value to zero to effectively return it to it's original state), and then we pass the list to the refreshList method to databind it and populate the ComboBox.

Tested using VS2012, Windows Forms, .Net 4.0 (with a Thread.Sleep to emulate the time taken for N.getList)

*WorkerReportsProgress, and the associated ReportProgress method/event are used when you want to increment the progress bar - you can tell the GUI that you are 10% done, 20% done, 50% done etc etc.

Comment: Your afford is successful. Thanks a lot.